# R method for a function

Tags: r

I have a constructor built function(Bond.Valuation).  The result of which is a superclass of other classes, BondAnalytics.  Now, from what I have read, I need to create methods on the class BondAnalytics.  Reading Chambers book I have done the following:

When I type Bond.Valuation it says its a standard generic.  So, show will work on it?

```
method.skeleton("show", c("BondAnalytics")).
```

So, I think this uses the generic function "show" on any object of BondAnalytics.

The command to method.skeleton produces:

```
setMethod("show",
    signature(object = "BondAnalytics"),
    function (object) 
    {
       cat("Bond Valuation\n")
       cat(BondID:);print(object@ID)

    }
)
```

So, I think that show is a generic function that is now associated with this method and signature is class BondAnalytics, so this method will match itself to anything the matches class BondAnalytics.

So basically, I just have to define what I want to show from Bond.Valuation.  What if I wanted a combination of text and a plot?  Is that one method of methods in methods

Comment: “Is this the function Bond.Valuation?” – no, it’s the function `show`, as the code clearly indicates.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful!  I have edited my post.  So, my function is already a standard generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct. The method "show" you just declared will be associated with the BondAnalytics class. In this method you can do anything you want to. If you want to you can display summary statistics or plot some information about the object or do both.

This is from the manual for "show":

```
Display the object, by printing, plotting or whatever suits its
class.  This function exists to be specialized by methods.  The
default method calls ‘showDefault’.
```

It basically says you can do whatever you want to.